# Can I uninstall local sql server 2014 if I use SSMS to remote into main server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I use SSMS 18 with our servers located on a Windows Server 2012 VM.

I would like to remove the local SQL Server 2014 instance that is installed on my personal PC.  Is there any reason I cannot do this?

Answer (score 2):

SSMS and the SQL Server Data Engine are completely separate products and are also distributed separately (the latter since 2014).

They do not share any required installation media that the other application installs, so you can install one without the other without issue, or remove one without affecting the other as well.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I knew that but wanted to have some confirmation before I did anything stupid.